# How do I profile the underlying C-code in an R package?

Tags: c, r, profiling

I have a pretty good understanding of C but very little of R. I have installed an R-package (coxme) into R-studio on Windows7 from source which included compiling several C files into a .dll. This package is not standalone and depends on at least 2 other packages (maybe more). It runs too slow so I would like to see if I can speed it up by profiling it first. I used the R-package "profvis" to profile the R-code but it only tells me that 98% of the time get used by the "coxme" package without giving any further details. The call to the R package looks something like:

```
frail.xg=coxme(Surv(y.vec,delta.vec)~x.mat+g.vec+(1|fiid.vec),varlist=list(K.mat))
```

The entire package has no function named `coxme(...)`, so I have no idea what goes on after I call this package as shown above. I tagged every function inside the "src" directory of the package to print (append) to a file, but only the `init()` function fires upon installation when it registers the package. Non of the other functions print to that file once I run coxme from within R-Studio. Besides the `init()` function it seems that non of the C-functions in the package even get executed when I call `coxme(...)`. My approach is like:

```
remove.packages("coxme")
```

manipulate C-code in coxme "src" directory to print to some external file "I am function XYZ, etc.". create coxme.tar.gz

```
install.packages('E:/Workdir/AOO/R/coxme/coxme.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")
library("coxme")
frail.xg=coxme(Surv(y.vec,delta.vec)~x.mat+g.vec(1|fiid.vec),varlist=list(K.mat))
```

this produces some expected result.
But non of the C-functions seem to get hit, nor does my profiling code. So my questions are:

1. What exactly gets executed?
2. How do I go about and find out what's eating up most of the time within the coxme package?

Comment: Maybe try to answer first a more immediate concern: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: `coxme` calls `coxme.fit` which calls a C function: https://github.com/cran/coxme/blob/master/R/coxme.fit.R#L152

Comment: OK, that's interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help [how to find the source of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function)

Comment: Also maybe this would help: https://www.jimhester.com/2018/08/22/debugging-rstudio/

Comment: I have the source code. It just won't print to an external file. fopen() does return a valid filehandle but still no printing takes place.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that Rstudio (at least on Windows7) does not update any .dll once it was loaded. So my edits of the C-code never took effect since the old .dll was never replaced, even when I unloaded and recompiled via install.packages(). I had to completely exit Rstudio and manually delete the package directory (coxme). Then restart Rstudio in install from my edited source. Now my edits deliver the desired results.

Comment: You might try the `More > Clean & Rebuild` option in the `Build` pane to force erasing the `.o`/`.so` objects before reinstalling

Comment: Did you success to speed up the `coxme` package ? I'm using it and it takes 3 seconds to get an estimation for 2500 individuals which is too slow for me. I have  to bootstrap it.